# How can I programatically create Test Steps in SoapUI?

Tags: groovy, soapui

I am looking to automatically create Test Steps in an existing SoapUI project. Each test step is loaded from recorded SOAP requests saved in individual files. Every test step can have the same assertions, copied from another test step.

I think I can do something using Groovy in a Setup Script. Are there any other options I could use?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, using the [WsdlTestStepFactory](http://www.soapui.org/apidocs/index.html?com/eviware/soapui/impl/wsdl/teststeps/registry/WsdlTestStepFactory.html) from Groovy.

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of different test steps. For groovy test step you can try this:

```
    public String createGroovyScriptTestStep() {
    try {
        String projectName = "C:\\YourProjectName.xml";
        File projectFile = new File(projectName);
        WsdlProjectPro project = new WsdlProjectPro(projectName);

        if (!projectFile.exists()) {
            return "no_project_already_exists";
        }

        WsdlTestSuite testSuite = project
                .getTestSuiteByName("TestSuiteName");

        if (testSuite == null) {
            return "testsuite does not exist";
        } else {
            WsdlTestCase testCase = testSuite
                    .getTestCaseByName("TestCaseName");

            if (testCase == null) {
                return "testcase does not exist";
            } else {

                if (testCase.getTestStepByName("StepName") != null) {

                    return "teststep_already_exists";
                }

                WsdlGroovyScriptTestStep testStep = (WsdlGroovyScriptTestStep) testCase
                        .addTestStep(GroovyScriptStepFactory.GROOVY_TYPE,
                                "StepName");

                testStep.setDescription("Description");
                testStep.setScript("System.out.println('Hi')");

                project.saveIn(projectFile);

                return "teststep_successfully_created";
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

You need following Maven dependecies:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.github.redfish4ktc.soapui</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-soapui-extension-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>4.6.4.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fifesoft</groupId>
        <artifactId>rsyntaxtextarea</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.1</version>
    </dependency>
```